# How to get a dictionary with Linq where keys are met more than once?

Tags: c#, linq

Assuming an object such as:

```
class A {
  string Country;
  string Region;
}
```

And an `IEnumerable<A>` such as:

```
    "Denmark", "Arhus"
    "Denmark", "Bornholm"
    "Denmark", "Frederiksborg"
    "Denmark", "Fyn"
    "Denmark", "Copenhagen"
    "Denmark", "Nordjylland"
    "France", "Alsace"
    "France", "Aquitaine"
    "France", "Auvergne"
    "France", "Basse-Normandie"
    "France", "Bourgogne"
    "France", "Bretagne"
    "France", "Centre"
    "France", "Champagne-Ardenne"
    "France", "Corse"
    etc...
```

How can I obtain an `IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> res` with Linq where `res['Country']` would return an `IEnumerable<string>` of the corresponding regions ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ToLookup` should give you exactly what you want.

```
var lookup = data.ToLookup(a => a.Country, a=> a.Region);
```

Technically it's immutable, and as such doesn't implement `IDictionary`.  If it's essential that you implement that interface then you'll need to convert the lookup to a dictionary:

```
var dictionary = lookup.ToDictionary(group => group.Key, 
    group => group.AsEnumerable());
```

Answer (score 3):

```
IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> dictionary =
    list.GroupBy(r => r.Country)
    .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.Select(t => t.Region));
```

Comment: @I4V They are not they same but similar. `Lookup` is immutable `Dictionary` is not. `lookup["Key"]` returns an empty sequence for non existing keys while dictionary throws `KeyNotFoundException`.